# Java SQL query, most efficient check for matching column value?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have a table which will potentially have 200 to 300 thousand rows.

**I need to check if a primary key exists in a table.**

Here is what i have so far:

```
public boolean checkIfKeyExists(String userkey) {
    try {
        connection = getSQLConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT userkey FROM " + keytable + " WHERE userkey = ?");
        ps.setString(1, userkey);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        boolean set = false;
        while(rs.next()){
            set = true;
        }
        close(ps,rs);
        return set;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Error.execute(plugin, ex);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Having to use a result set and setting a boolean off that just seems too lengthy for a simple key check you know? 
What is the simplest way of doing this?

Comment: If it's a primary key and you check for equality, you should get one row at most. The operation shouldn't be too lengthy.

Comment: @fabian are you the fabian from codecanyon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a way around using the result set, but you could get around having to set the boolean by just doing

```
return ps.executeQuery().next();
```

and then close your statement and resultset in the `finally` block.

Comment: this returns true/false whether or not there's a result?

Comment: @ThatGuy343 Not according to the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next()). And in your original implementation, you were also basing yourself on the result of `next()` to set your flag.

Comment: Definitely a more efficient way of going about it.

Answer (score 1):

Using your variables, you can have

```
set = rs.next();
```

Alsi in SQL part you can have `SELECT 1 ...` which will work a tad faster.

Comment: so if i put "SELECT 1 FROM keytable" it's the same as "SELECT userkey"?

Comment: Content of resultset will obviously be different but number of rows the same.